# I am facing this problem while running react application. how to solve this issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

Error: Cannot find module 'E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\react6\my-app\demo\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js'
Require stack:

- E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\react6\my-app\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\react6\my-app\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\react6\my-app\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\react6\my-app\demo\node_modules\webpack-manifest-plugin\dist\index.js
- E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\react6\my-app\demo\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
- E:\10th semester\oop2(C#)\After_Semester\react6\my-app\demo\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\build.js

Comment: Did you install the dependencies of the project?

Comment: how to install it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have missiong dependencies. Open terminal in root of your project and run command `npm install`. It will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There might be dependencies that are not installed yet. Try checking your package.json file and check if all dependencies are listed there. If not, try running `npm install`.